# How to punctuate quoted sentences?

Tags: puntuación, citas

I've found lots of information online about proper punctuation (after the quotation marks) when a dialogue tag is used. However, I cannot find any reference regarding if the quotation or dialogue line is a complete sentence without any tag.

Which is a better way of punctuating that sentence (when translated into a Spanish dialogue)?

> "The dog is blue".

or

> "The dog is blue."

Comment: So your question is: When does closing punctuation fall inside or outside of the quotation marks in Spanish? Note in English the rules for this vary between US and British English.

Comment: Thanks. I'm receiving conflicting advice about where to put a period when the quoted material is a complete sentence/thought. Can't find anything on the internet that addresses it as they all include a dialogue tag, like {He said}.  In my translation, I have just the quote: “Me estoy sometiendo.”
“Así como al Señor.” 
or "Me estoy sometiendo". and "Así como al Señor".

Answer (score 6):

According to the RAE (Real Academia Española), the period has to be placed outside the quotation mark, so the correct form is:

> "The dog is blue".

See the reference about the [usage of punto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT) (dot):

> 3. Combinación con otros signos
>
> 3.1. **El punto se escribirá siempre detrás de las comillas**, los paréntesis y las rayas de cierre: *Dijo: «Tú y yo hemos terminado».
>   Tras estas palabras se marchó, dando un portazo. (Creo que estaba muy
>   enfadada). En la calle la esperaba Emilio —un buen amigo—. Este, al
>   verla llegar, sonrió.*

And also the reference about the [usage of comillas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX) (quotation marks):

> a) Los signos de puntuación correspondientes al período en el que va
>   inserto el texto entre comillas se colocan siempre después de las
>   comillas de cierre:
>
> > *Sus palabras fueron: «No lo haré»; pero al final nos ayudó.*
> >
> > *¿De verdad ha dicho «hasta nunca»?*
>
> b) El texto que va dentro de las comillas tiene una puntuación
>   independiente y lleva sus propios signos ortográficos. Por eso, si el
>   enunciado entre comillas es interrogativo o exclamativo, los signos de
>   interrogación y exclamación se escriben dentro de las comillas:
>
> > *Le preguntó al conserje: «¿Dónde están los baños, por favor?».*
> >
> > *«¡Qué ganas tengo de que lleguen las vacaciones!», exclamó.*
>
> De esta regla debe excluirse el punto, que se escribirá detrás de las
>   comillas de cierre cuando el texto entrecomillado ocupe la parte final
>   de un enunciado o de un texto (→ c).
>
> c) Cuando lo que va entrecomillado constituye el final de un enunciado
>   o de un texto, debe colocarse punto detrás de las comillas de cierre,
>   incluso si delante de las comillas va un signo de cierre de
>   interrogación o de exclamación, o puntos suspensivos:
>
> > *«No está el horno para bollos». Con estas palabras zanjó la discusión y se marchó.*
> >
> > *«¿Dónde te crees que vas?». Esa pregunta lo detuvo en seco.*
> >
> > *«Si pudiera decirle lo que pienso realmente...». A Pedro no le resultaba fácil hablar con sinceridad.*
>
> En el caso de que deba colocarse una llamada de nota que afecte a todo
>   el texto entrecomillado, esta debe colocarse entre las comillas de
>   cierre y el punto.
>
> > Rafael Lapesa señalaba que «es muy discutido el posible influjo de las
> >     lenguas indígenas en la pronunciación del español de América»<sup>1</sup>.
> >
> > <sup>1</sup> Historia de la lengua española, p. 545.
>
> Si la nota solo hace referencia a la última palabra del texto
>   entrecomillado, la llamada debe colocarse delante de las comillas de
>   cierre:
>
> > *Rodolfo Lenz llegó a afirmar que el habla vulgar de Chile era  «principalmente español con sonidos araucanos<sup>1</sup>».*
> >
> > *<sup>1</sup> El araucano o mapuche es la lengua que hablaban los naturales de la antigua región de Arauco, en la zona central de Chile.*

Comment: This is the usage I prefer, and I find more logical, but I've seen it the other way around, too.

Comment: Yes, so have I @MikMik . Only that the RAE states this is the official way.

Comment: Funnily enough, the Spanish Wikipedia standard for footnotes adds them *after* the punctuation, not before, as RAE recommends.

Comment: @Gorpik it is probably a copy of the English style

Comment: @fedorqui I'm pretty sure, but it is unusual for Spanish Wikipedia not to follow RAE recommendations in its style guide.

Comment: @Gorpik I've looked for some examples and indeed found them ([example](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacertilia)). However, do you refer to the official documentation from Wikipedia, explaining _how to add footnotes_? If so, could you share the link? Thanks!

Comment: Here it is: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Referencias#Notas_al_pie_(llamadas_de_nota)_y_su_combinaci%C3%B3n_con_referencias As you can see, they have based this standard in a Alberto Montaner's *Prontuario de blibliografía*.

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista en español el punto se pone después del cierre de las comillas. Porque el punto representa el fin de la oración, y no el fin de la frase citada entre comillas. Ejemplo:

> Necesitarán comprar el libro “psicología básica”.

Si en este caso pusiéramos el punto antes del cierre de comillas la oración se quedara sin finalizar (con punto), por decirlo de alguna forma:

> Necesitarán comprar el libro “psicología básica.”

De esta forma no tiene sentido porque la comilla de cierre también forma parte de la oración mientras que se está quedando fuera.

Comment: Sí, parece un caso agradable en el que la teoría (véase mi respuesta) y el sentido común van de la mano : )