# ¿Cuál es el criterio para los signos de puntuación dentro de citas?

Tags: puntuación, citas

Leyendo un libro me encuentro con lo siguiente:

> (...) "¡Qué gran idea!", escribió otro de sus admiradores. "Veremos si los políticos son lo bastante valientes para **adoptarla." Los** colaboradores más prácticos propusieron hacer una recogida de firmas en su apoyo, (...).

La parte que me interesa es la que resalto en negrita, donde se cita una frase, se incluye ese punto en la cita, se cierran las comillas y se continúa con una nueva frase.

Entiendo que sería incorrecto escribir un punto en la cita y otro tras las comillas:

> (...) "Veremos si los políticos son lo bastante valientes para **adoptarla.". Los** colaboradores más prácticos propusieron hacer una recogida de firmas en su apoyo, (...).

Sin embargo, me pregunto en qué casos sería correcto hacer lo contrario: escribir el punto tras cerrar la citación:

> (...) "Veremos si los políticos son lo bastante valientes para **adoptarla". Los** colaboradores más prácticos propusieron hacer una recogida de firmas en su apoyo, (...).

Comment: Esto es más profundo. Lo he visto con el tema de los signos interrogativos dentro de las comillas — En inglés acostumbran harto a hacer esto, y rara vez lo he visto en español.

Comment: @Ustanak por si es de utilidad, el libro es una traducción del inglés.

Comment: Eso confirma lo que pensaba. Me da la impresión de que la regla viene de allá y no es aplicable al español. En todo caso no tengo fuentes para ello, solamente estoy especulando.

Comment: Ya respondiste la pregunta :D [Punctuating quoted sentences](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/punctuating-quoted-sentences)

Comment: @rsanchez oh vaya memoria la mía :| Muchas gracias por encontrar el duplicado (había buscado pero no en inglés jaja). Por tanto, **deducimos que la forma en la que se escribió en el libro es incorrecta y debería ser _... adoptarla". Los colaboradores..._**