# "Chav" en inglés, ¿qué palabras se usan para designar un "quillo", "cani", "naco"... según países y zonas?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos

En los últimos años se ha popularizado en el inglés británico el concepto de [**chav**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chav_(subcultura)), que la Wikipedia en español define como:

> *Chav, chava, charva o charver*, es un término peyorativo aplicado a ciertos jóvenes del Reino Unido. La imagen estereotipada de un chav corresponde al de un adolescente o joven adulto agresivo, con origen en la clase trabajadora, que viste ropas de marca y tiene estilo informal. Además, tiene por costumbre pelear y ser altanero, suele involucrarse en crímenes triviales o menores, y frecuentemente está desempleado o con un empleo de bajo salario.

Ha dado pie a un libro muy interesante (*Chavs: la demonización de la clase obrera*, de [Owen Jones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Jones_(escritor)) —que dio pie a [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17622/1674) por mi parte—) y su imagen característica viene dada por el personaje [Vicky Pollard](http://littlebritain.wikia.com/wiki/Vicky_Pollard) de la serie [Little Britain](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Britain):

> [image: Vicky Pollard]

Esta imagen seguro que os resulta conocida, pues este perfil social puede encontrarse en otros países. Por tanto, me pregunto: **¿qué palabra en castellano define este concepto de manera similar?**

En España me suenan **quillo** para chico y **choni** para chica. En especial, *choni* mantiene el sentido peyorativo de *chav*, si bien *quillo* no lo hace y suele ser más bien usado para nombrar el chico joven con pendientes, ropa de marca y moto ruidosa.

Comment: En Andalucía usamos _quillo_ (y su forma aún más corta _illo_) para referirnos a cualquiera: "-¿Cuándo quedamos, quillo?". Su significado no es más que el de "chiquillo", palabra de la que procede. Aquí el masculino de "choni" es "cani".

Comment: Jeje temía y a la vez deseaba que esto pasara: el uso de _quillo_ varía mucho según la región de España. En el norte, [quillo es más o menos antónimo de pijo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/quillo-quiyo-en-el-norte-de-espa%C3%B1a.1516556/?hl=es), mientras que _cani_ no se usa en absoluto.

Comment: cani, choni, chav son palabras absolutamente desconocidas para mi. Tenemos algunas palabras que encajan parcialmente pero tal perfil social no es frecuente por estos lados. Aquí, la persona que viste ropa de marca generalmente no se involucra en crímenes menores ni tiene trabajo de baja remuneración y viceversa.

Comment: I think the implication about _ropa de marca_ is that they buy clothes of a specific label or labels. The quality of these is an open question.

Comment: @mdewey no, in fact _ropa de marca_ is generally understood (or at least in Spain) as expensive brands. In this specific case, expensive sport brands: Nike, Adidas...

Comment: @DGaleano en base a [tu respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26191/1674), añadí _ñero_ en la respuesta de aquí.

Comment: Creo que nadie ha mencionado todavía un clásico (aunque posiblemente demasiado genérico para lo que se anda preguntando) que además está admitido por la RAE: "niñato".

Comment: quillo viene de chiquillo y no es igual que chav.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como van apareciendo palabras distintas según la región en la que cada uno reside, las recojo en una lista para que cada cual pueda incluir la suya:

- ***Chile***

  - m. y f. **flaite**
  - m. y f. **cuma**
  - m. y f. **punga**
  - m. y f. **pelusa, pelusón** (anticuado)
- ***Colombia***

  - m. **ñero**
- ***España***

  - f. **choni**
  - m. y f. **poligonero, poligonera**
  - *Zona norte*

    - m. **quillo**
  - *Aragón*

    - m. **co**
  - *Zona sur*

    - m. **cani**
  - *Zona sureste*

    - m. y f. **jincho, jincha**
- ***México***

  - m. y f. **naco, naca**
  - *Zona centro*

    - m. y f. **chairo, chaira**
  - *Zona norte*

    - m. y f. **paisa** (*neutral*), **paisita** (*peyorativo*)

Comment: Esta respuesta es la mejor. Falta enriquecerla con los modismos equivalentes en otras regiones.

Comment: Agregue. Contenido de mi respuesta para incluir los regionalismos de México, lo coloque en su lugar pues la lista esta ordenada de Sur a norte y este a oeste.

Comment: @hlecuanda qué bien, muchísimas gracias por tus aportaciones. Si te apetece agregar contenido específico de México a este tipo de preguntas, en [esta respuesta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) hay un listado de ellas.

Comment: *Poligonero/a* se usa en más zonas de España, no solo Canarias (hace referencia a los polígonos industriales donde se ubican ciertas discotecas), pero no sé exactamente en qué zonas.

Comment: @fedorqui No soy habitual del sitio y todavía no conozco bien los usos y normas. ¿Podrías añadir el término "merdellón/a" que apunta Charlie? Y habría que indicar de alguna forma que el término "quillo" en la Zona Sur de España no tiene connotaciones negativas ni suele aplicarse al colectivo en cuestión

Comment: Al que ha puesto esa lista, en Aragón no decimos - CO- para referirnos a esta gente. Co viene de chico y no hace referencia a ninguna persona en particular

Answer (score 2):

Definitivamente, tras leer la definición en Urban Dictionary de [*chav*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chav), la traducción directa al español es [**cani**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cani) para hombres y [**choni**](http://quesignificado.com/choni/) para mujeres.

Nótese en todo caso que estas palabras pueden estar sujetas a fuertes variaciones locales. Por ejemplo, en Málaga (España) ambas palabras se reducen a "merdellón/a".

Comment: Creo que por su naturaleza coloquial y reciente es un término condenado a muchas variaciones locales. En Chile un término con campo semántico aproximado podría ser _flaite_ en la actualidad, con _cuma_, _pelusa(són)_ como ideas afines más antiguas. Los tres se usan como sust. y adj., m. y f., con la excepción de _pelusón(a)_

Comment: @Rafael y un _flaite_ se viste con ropa fina de marca? Busqué la definición en Asihablamos.com y se parece mucho a lo que en Colombia llamamos _valija o chirrete_ que es una persona indecente de gustos ordinarios, mal hablada, pero generalmente es de clase social baja por lo que la vestimenta no es fina ni de marca.

Comment: @DGaleano, diría que la palabra _flaite_ tiene más de una acepción, pero una de las dos principales incluye ropa de _ciertas marcas_ caras y notorias (no infrecuentemente robadas, falsas o asumiendo un costo desproporcionado al presupuesto del individuo), como forma de ostentación. A veces también incluye cortes de pelo/peinados específicos (con influencia reggaetonera). Tiene algo de idiosincrático que acá la gente con nivel educacional más alto tiende a preferir lo sobrio/menos notorio (aunque cada vez menos).