# ¿Por qué se usa "gepeto" para referirse a la cara?

Tags: modismos, coloquialismos, españa

Leyendo una de mis webs de cine favoritas, me encontré con una noticia que involucraba a Nicole Kidman. Leyendo los comentarios, que a veces son graciosísimos, me encontré con esto:

> [image]
>
> Qué buena estaba ahí Nicole Kidman y qué enfermedad mental hay que tener para ponerse el **gepeto** de plástico como lo tiene ahora...

El comentario hace referencia a la actriz pasando por el quirófano y dejándose la cara peor de lo que estaba.

A la cara a veces se la denomina `jeta`, `hocico`, `morro`, `careto` (de *careta*, supongo), etc. Si no recuerdo mal "Gepetto" era el padre de Pinocho.

¿Por qué se usa "gepeto" para referirse a la cara?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que es una forma propia de España, más famosa hace unos diez años y relacionada con un programa de televisión.

He encontrado un par de referencias. Una de ellas es en ForoCoches en el hilo ["no me vuelvas a mirar al gepeto"](http://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=2023127#post73885411):

> Gepeto, dícese de expresión que usó hace unos años una petarda de Gran hermano para referirse al "jeto" (oséase, cara) que se ha extendido entre las clases más analfabetas de la sociedad al igual que expresiones como "asín" "trasgibersar" "darse una idea" etc...

Otro tercia:

> Lo de gepeto se usaba mucho hace cosa de 9-10 años.

También hay referencias en [tuBabel](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/37046-gepeto-jepeto-gepetto-jepetto), donde está etiquetada como propia de España:

> Del original "jeta", cara, por modificación de gérero se derivó en "jeto". "Se ríe en mi gepeto".
>
> Por alguna extraña modificación o cruce por homofonía o homografía "jeto" se hizo sinónimo de Gepetto, el padre de Pinocho.
> Suena raro, pero es la única explicación que le veo.

Dado que el hilo de ForoCoches data de 2011, restándole los 9-10 años saltamos a 2001, que es la época en la que empezó a emitirse con gran éxito [Gran Hermano en España](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Hermano_(Espa%C3%B1a)). Por tanto, todo aquello que se dijera allí por parte de sus concursantes tenía mucho eco en las conversaciones de la gente y considero normal que un deje de alguno de ellos calara en la cultura popular. Dicho lo cual, yo nunca he oído *gepeto* en este contexto.

---

<sub>Para aquellos que no lo conozcan, ForoCoches es un foro muy utilizado en España por la cultura popular. En él se habla con profusión de conceptos como el [*cuñadismo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19090/1674) y el [*chavismo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17854/1674), por ejemplo.</sub>

Comment: De acuerdo con la explicación. Con lo único que no estoy de acuerdo es con algo que dice el comentarista de tuBabel; este tipo de modificaciones no es raro ni extraño. Usar una palabra por otra similar con fines más o menos humorísticos es habitual.

Comment: Es la primera vez que escucho eso. Saludos desde México.

Comment: @Maurocrispin yo tampoco lo había escuchado nunca y vivo en España, donde se supone que se usa :)

Comment: Dudo mucho que tenga que ver con Gran Hermano, quizá la popularizó pero yo he oído y usado esa palabra bastante antes de que existiera el programa.

Answer (score 2):

Forma(ba) parte de la jerga adolescente de finales de los 90 y principios de los 2000 del área metropolitana de Madrid. Se trata(ba) de una especie de "jerga cockney" a la española, en el que las palabras propias de la jerga se sustituían por palabras que empezaban por las mismas sílabas, con fines meramente jocosos.

Por ejemplo, también pasaba con los dientes, a los que coloquialmente se les llama(ba) piños, de piños se pasaba a piñata: si la palabra ya existía y su significado no tenía nada que ver, era perfecta.

Más ejemplos: en vez de "al loro" (expresión para pedir atención a algo curioso o significativo) decíamos "al Loreto"... seguro que había más casos parecidos que ahora no me vienen a la memoria.

Pues con jeto, decíamos Gepetto. Teníamos 15 años y éramos la primera horneada de la LOGSE; tampoco le queráis encontrar más lógica al asunto.

Comment: Entiendo. Lo que faltaría en la respuesta quizá, para atar todos lo cabos, es a partir de qué evolucionó "gepeto". Tal vez de "jeta", que empieza por un sonido similar y se refiere a a la cara.