# ¿Cuál es el origen de "ñero"? ¿En qué contexto se usa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, méxico, sustantivos

Escuchando una canción de Molotov, un grupo de música de México, me fijé en que su título es *Ñero*. Leída [la letra](https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=803218) veo que menciona cosas como:

> Ñero, ñero
> Ya todos sabemos quién es el mero mero
> La raza te quiere te quiere ver de güero
> Seguro a Acapulco pal fin de semana
> Y mientras yo cuido a tu hermana

No conocía la palabra y en el DAMER encontré:

> #### [**ñero, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=%C3%B1ero). <sub>(Apócope de *compañero*).</sub>
>
> **I. 1.**    m. y f. *Mx, Ho, ES, Ve; Co:N,SO.* juv. Amigo íntimo, compañero inseparable. pop + cult → espon. (**ñeris**).
>  **II. 1.**    m. y f. *Mx, Co:C.* Persona de bajo estrato social, marginado. pop + cult → espon ^ desp.
> **III. 1.**    sust/adj. *Ve.* Persona tonta o de escaso entendimiento. pop + cult → espon.

Parece claro que se trata de una sustitución de *compañero* por *ñero*, que con el tiempo se ha estandarizado.

Sin embargo, [miro con Google Trends y comparo con *compañero* en México](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=MX&q=%C3%B1ero,compa%C3%B1ero) y me encuentro con que esta última cada vez sale más:

> [image]

Y luego, también veo que parece buscarse desde la parte interior de México:

> [image]

Por todo ello, mis preguntas son:

- ¿Con qué frecuencia se utiliza?
- Además de en México, ¿dónde se utiliza?
- ¿En qué contextos? Formales, informales, juveniles...
- ¿Con qué significado suele utilizarse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En Colombia **ñero** viene de *compañero* y tiene dos significados conexos.

Ñero es usada principalmente en el lenguaje de la calle por indigentes y demás. Entre ellos se llaman ñero el uno al otro, por lo que el resto de personas comenzaron a usar ñero para referirse a las personas de la calle, especialmente a los que antes se llamaba [gamines](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?key=gam%EDn).

Ej #1. Entre *habitantes de calle*:

> "Ñero pídale una luca a esa cucha." = "Amigo pídale 1000 pesos a esa señora."

Ej #2. Otro tipo de persona:

> "Mejor no vamos a esa zona que eso está lleno de ñeros." = "Mejor no vamos a esa zona que eso está lleno de habitantes de calle."

Algunos ejemplos más [aquí](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/%C3%91ero.php).

Por ser una palabra despectiva para referirse a un "[gamín](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?key=gam%EDn)", también puede usarse para referirse a cualquier persona que presente un comportamiento ordinario o grosero, como se puede leer en este escrito: [*Como identificar un ñero*](https://www.las2orillas.co/aprenda-identificar-nero/), del cual extraigo el siguiente párrafo:

> Ñero es el que usa los pantalones debajo de las nalgas, pero no porque no tenga cinturón, por el contrario, lleva uno con chapa metálica enorme. Ñero es el que usa cachuchas con la visera recta cubriendo una de sus orejas. Ñero es el que escucha música en el trasporte público en un miniparlante (pero sin audífonos). Ñero es el que se sube a los buses a vender dulces o lapiceros baratos con una retahíla memorizada que lleva un seseo insoportable. Ñero es el que se pone la camiseta del equipo de fútbol aun en los días en que no juega. Ñero es el que se hace el corte de cabello llamado “el 7”. Ñero es al que le llega el regueetón al corazón. Ñero es el que pinta grafitis de letras góticas ilegibles. Ñero es el que usa camisas marca Ralph Lauren, Polo, Tommy Hilfiger o La coast (imitación eso sí) con un logotipo exageradamente enorme. Ñero es el que se deja la barba tan delgada como un hilo. Ñero es el que se hace figuras en la cabeza con una máquina de afeitar. Ñero es el que dice: “sisas”, “mi pez” o “mi perro”. Ñero es el que siempre lleva consigo un puñal.
>
> ¡Ojo! Pero quiero que quede algo muy claro antes que me tachen de fascista y es que una cosa es ser pobre y otra muy distinta es ser ñero. Porque si bien todo ñero es pobre, no todo pobre es ñero.

Comment: ¡Anda! Es decir que podrían relacionar con los [_canis_](http://www.detribusurbanas.com/canis/) españoles. ¿O los [_chavs_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17854/1674) ingleses?

Comment: no es fascismo, pero es division de clases sociales. un diminuto defecto en el cerebro del ser humano que nos hace pensar que somos diferentes y mejores/peores que otros.

Comment: @Mike ojo que eso es parte del artículo de la referencia. Yo solo lo estoy citando. Lo que dices es correcto ñero es despectivo cuando se usa con el segundo significado.

Comment: @fedorqui la referencia menciona: _"Naco en Mexico, Cani en España, Turro en Argentina, Tukki en Venezuela o Flaite en chile"_

Comment: @walen pues añádelo en la respuesta wiki de los [chavs](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17854/chav-en-castellano)

Comment: Genial el texto para identificar *ñeros*. Hoy aprendí que si *te gusta la gasolina* o *pides más gasolina* eres ñero. Cosas veredes! :)

Answer (score 2):

Siendo correcta la respuesta anterior, me gustaría agregar lo que sería una tercera acepción de *ñero*: indicar peligro inherente o situacional, o una forma de referirse a la ansiedad causada por encontrarse en una situación de peligro, independiente de la presencia de indigentes o ciudadanos menos afortunados.

> Ese paseo en montaña rusa está bien ***ñero***.
>
> Cuando pasaron los comandos de la policía federal, todos sentimos bien ***ñero*** aquí en el estómago.
>
> ¿Qué transita por tus venas, aparte de colesterol?
>
> *Chale* pues nada carnal ya ves que todo está bien ***ñero*** con la economía si no, hasta las aguas negras del imperialismo yanki ¡y diharina!

Este uso es particular del Distrito Federal y zonas conurbadas del estado de México y el estado de Puebla. Escuchar que alguien use ***ñero*** en este sentido es casi garantía de que dicha persona es habitante o recibió su educación básica en la mancha urbana de la Ciudad de México.

Cabe mencionar que aunque folclórica y divertida palabra y sin duda, parte del legado cultural e identidad regional y nacional del país, está dentro de una clase de vocablos que sin ser efectivamente altisonante, no se considerarían como lenguaje apropiado para su uso en presencia de amable compañía, y el uso indiscriminado de los mismos puede crear una percepción de que el usuario no es particularmente sofisticado, o ha tenido una educación punto menos que estelar. En otras palabras usar ***ñero*** es algo muy *naco*.

Comment: _naco_ y _diharina_ no las entendí :)

Comment: *naco* es la voz mexicana para el *chav* británico. No son consecuencia o causa uno del otro, pero usualmente la decoración y vocabulario de un *naco* son totalmente *kitsch*. *Naco* y *Fresa* son mutuamente excluyentes pero es válido aspirar a convertirse en el "más fresa de los *nacos* ya que ser el más naco de los *fresa* es considerado una situacion. Picoo edificante y que debería ser corregida

Comment: "diharina" es un juego de palabras usado con cierta frecuencia, su significado es "*diario* o *diariamente* como periodo regular. El juego de palabras es una mala pronunciación de la frase "de harina". Para desarrollar un buen hábito debes practicarlo *diharina*

Comment: No sé si dar `upvote` por la detallada explicación o dar `downvote` por la referencia y las palabras usadas, ese ejemplo estuvo bien *naco* :P

Answer (score 1):

Dado el contexto que proporciona el autor de la pregunta (una canción de un grupo mexicano), considero apropiado echar un vistazo a la definición que da el [Diccionario del Español de México](http://dem.colmex.mx/):

> Persona que se considera vulgar, carente de educación por pertenecer a una clase social baja: “Habla como *ñero*”, “Está muy *ñero* su galán”