# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "hacer la cama a alguien"? ¿Por qué es algo malo?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

[*Hacer la cama a alguien*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacerle_la_cama_a_alguien) significa:

> Actuar a espaldas de una persona de forma de conseguir que esta caiga en desgracia y conseguir una ventaja personal con el cambio de situación.

Por ejemplo: un político A habla con otro B sobre la conveniencia de que dimita. Cuando B dimite, de repente A se postula como sustituto para el cargo que tenía B... Claramente, A le ha hecho la cama a B.

El RAE lo describe:

> [**hacerle a alguien la cama**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=cama)
>   1. loc. verb. Trabajar en secreto para perjudicarlo.

En el [NTLLE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2515/1674) he encontrado esta definición ya en 1956 y no la encuentro antes. El *Mapa de diccionarios* la incluye en 1992 y 2001, pero en 1925 y antes, no... si bien en 1780 recoge:

> HACERLE LA CAMA Á ALGUNO, Ó Á ALGUNA COSA
>   . f. met. y fam. Ir disponiendo los medios con arte, ó cautela para conseguir algun fin. *Vias cautè parare ad finem assequendum*.

En el [CORDE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2519/1674), CREA y Corpes XXII no he encontrado entradas relevantes, lo que me hace pensar que es algo coloquial (como sospechaba) y pero claramente no nuevo por lo que vimos antes sobre 1780.

¿Cuál podría ser pues el origen de la expresión? ¿Por qué es algo malo si, de hecho, a todos nos encantaría que nos hicieran la cama y ahorrarnos unos minutillos cada mañana?

En España se utiliza con relativa frecuencia, ¿se usa también en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Y en el de Autoridades (tomo C, 1729): "Hacerle la cama a alguno, o a alguna cosa. Vale lo mismo que preparar y disponer de antemano lo conducente al fin que se pretende, antes de ponerlo en execución. Usase de ordinário de esta phrase en las matérias criminales: y assí, quando se quiere proceder contra algún reo para corregirle, o castigarle, se dice, Yá se le está haciendo, o se le tiene hecha la cama."

Comment: @Carlos caramba. Miré para atrás desde 1992 pero paré antes de 1925 al ver que no salía allí. Encontrarlo en 1780 me debería haber hecho buscar entorno a esas fechas, pero ya no lo hice.

Comment: Interesante el uso de _phrase_ en lugar de _frase_.

Comment: Sí, muy típico por entonces, igual que _execución_ por _ejecución_. En todo caso, sí que es cierto que en las ediciones a partir del siglo XIX ya no aparece esta expresión y no vuelve a aparecer hasta las fechas que tú mencionas.

Comment: Ah mira, de [Editions of Spanish Orthographies? / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/1674), en 1756 _Removed the “erudite” spellings (their words in the 1803 intro, not mine), mainly th, rh, ch /k/ and ph but not completely_ y luego en 1803-1806 _Complete removal of ph (always f)_.

Comment: @walen eso me hace pensar que tal vez _cama_ quería decir algo con una connotación más fuerte. Y de hecho, veo que en 1817 se define _cama_ como _10. ant. Lo mismo que SEPULCRO._

Comment: @walen puede que tengas razón, pero yo sigo viendo un significado diferente entre las acepciones del siglo XVIII y la actual. No sé si el hueco entre ambas definiciones (y hueco literal, porque durante décadas la expresión desapareció del diccionario) será lo suficientemente grande como para que cada definición tenga su propio origen, en vez de uno común.

Comment: Si la muerte es el sueño eterno, la sepultura es la cama. Parece una asociación razonable. Así, *hacer la cama* puede verse en paralelo con *cavar la tumba*, que también se usa en sentido figurado.

Comment: me ha parecido muy curiosa la pregunta, mas que nada por qué no tenía ni idea de esta expresión.

Comment: @BrianH. ¡curioso! En tu perfil veo que eres de España. Yo también y la oigo con cierta frecuencia en ambientes coloquiales.

Answer (score 3):

No consigo encontrar nada que avale esta respuesta, pero la pongo y a ver si luego la documento un poco.

No sé si a alguno se lo habrán hecho en el colegio, pero creo que todos nos podemos imaginar la típica travesura infantil que consiste en que un chaval se pone a cuatro patas detrás de otro sin que este se dé cuenta, y luego llega un tercero, le da un pequeño empujoncito, se tropieza con el que está detrás suya a gatas y se cae al suelo.

Creo que esa travesura es la que se llama "hacerle la cama a alguien"<sup>1</sup>, y de ahí se habrá expandido el término a su sentido más figurado: uno trabaja en secreto para perjudicar a otro (como si se pusiera a sus espaldas a cuatro patas para que se tropieze), esperando el momento en el que el más mínimo suceso le haga caer con todo el equipo.

---

<sup>1</sup> Preguntada a la RAE, [me responden](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/870551413646131200) diciendo que la acción perpetrada por la travesura mencionada no tiene nombre definido en español según sus registros.

Comment: Curioso, nunca había oído nombrar así a este juego, si bien tampoco lo había nombrado nunca :) Me parece plausible, así que de momento hago +1 a la espera de si podemos encontrar más fuentes. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui Hombre, más que "juego" yo diría "travesura". No sé por qué yo tenía entendido que se llamaba así, aunque me puedo equivocar, y lo malo es que sigo sin encontrar nada al respecto.

Comment: En el ámbito del deporte se llama *hacer la cama* a algo parecido (ponerse bajo un rival que está en el aire para que se caiga de espaldas al bajar). Es parecido a la travesura que mencionas.

Answer (score 3):

Me sorprende encontrarme esta expresión en tan castizas fuentes. En Argentina decimos generalmente *hacerle **una** cama a alguien* (y la cama suele ser con frecuencia una *camita*). (Vayan algunos ejemplos [aquí](http://www.eltrecetv.com.ar/la-noche-de-mirtha/gomez-centurion-me-hicieron-una-cama_088818), [aquí](http://www.losandes.com.ar/article/juan-pablo-videla-me-hicieron-una-cama) y [aquí](http://www.lacapital.com.ar/policiales/me-hicieron-una-cama-estoy-medio-una-guerra-politica-n415460.html).) La susodicha cama ya se usa por su cuenta también, dejando implícita la expresión, con el significado de "trampa".

Sospecho que el origen puede ser la idea de "hacerle la cama a alguien" como "dejar preparado algo en apariencia para que alguien se sienta cómodo". No se trata de una mera trampa o zancadilla sino de una situación en la que la víctima va feliz y contenta hacia el desastre.

Pensando en dichos similares se me ocurre que las variaciones sobre "dale una cuerda y se ahorcará solo" tienen que ver con esta clase de trampa. En efecto se habla de un perjuicio disfrazado de un favor y dispensado por la propia víctima.

Comment: Me pica mucho la curiosidad que en España digamos _la cama_ y allí _una cama_. O sea que en Argentina la _cama_ tendría un significado casi sinónimo a _trampa_ en cuanto a que se puede sustituir una palabra por la otra y tener una frase totalmente entendible, no ya una expresión: _hacerle una trampa a alguien_.

Comment: *Cama* como "trampa" no es el uso más común, pero se da bastante. Por ejemplo, puedo comentarle a alguien sobre un trato que me ofrecen y el otro puede opinar: "Eso es una cama". Se sobreentiende por "Eso es una cama que te quieren hacer", que también se usa.

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de toparme con esto:

> En las noches, los ciudadanos del Imperio Romano construí­an sus camas rellenando con paja un saco de tela. La paja debí­a ser vaciada cada noche para secarse, por eso, las camas tení­an que volverse a hacer cada noche. Esta práctica continuó hasta el siglo XV, y en algunos paí­ses todaví­a más tarde. De ahí­ proviene la expresión “hacer la cama”.
>
> Fuente: [este blog](http://ceslava.com/blog/el-origen-original-de-dichos-y-refranes-varios/)

La verdad es que es una de esos artículos en los que algunos de los orígenes de los dichos son creíbles e incluso contrastados y otros sabemos de sobra que son falsos, con lo cual no sabemos hasta qué punto fiarnos de los que no conocemos el origen. Eso sí, es [verificable](http://www.infocolchon.com/articulos/historia-colchon.html) que los romanos hacían sus camas de este modo.

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacer_la_cama) sí corrobora que

> El término «hacer la cama» proviene de la Edad Media, cuando las camas se construían tan solo con un manojo de paja que se extendía sobre el suelo o sobre un banco elevado. En vista de que la paja se recogía diariamente para secarla al sol o destinarla a otras funciones domésticas, la cama tenía que hacerse literalmente cada noche.1
>
> (La fuente para esta afirmación es *Las cosas nuestras de cada día, de Charles Panati*.)

Wikipedia aporta otros datos relacionados como que

> «Hacer la cama» es también una expresión coloquial que significa engañar a alguien para obtener algún provecho.

y que

> Una broma popular consiste en hacer la cama de una manera diferente para impedir que la persona entre en la misma. **Se llama hacer la petaca** (sábanas cortas, en Chile), y se realiza metiendo el extremo inferior de la sábana encimera por la cabecera volviéndola luego sobre la manta. De este modo, la persona que intenta entrar no lo consigue, al haber reducido con la sábana el espacio disponible.

Como apunta el [wiktionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacer_la_cama), la expresión tiene los significados de

> Actuar a espaldas de una persona de forma de conseguir que esta caiga en desgracia y conseguir una ventaja personal con el cambio de situación. ([hacerle la cama *a alguien*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacerle_la_cama_a_alguien))
>
> Engañar a alguno de manera premeditada y sutil con el fin de obtener provecho de su confusión.
>
> Preparar el terreno en sentido figurado para algún propósito que se tenga en mente; preparar una jugarreta a alguien.

Y esta última es la acepción que más cuadra, ya que si le preparas a alguien el "saco de paja" o la cama, se la puedes preparar mal de acuerdo a tus propósitos para hacerles una jugarreta o sacar beneficio de su confusión.

Así pues parece ser que "hacer la cama" es como la analogía de que preparas el lugar de descanso de otra persona de manera inconveniente para ella (le rellenas el saco con piedrecitas, no solo paja o plumas, le pones mal las sábanas, etc) para sacar provecho de esta jugarreta.

Answer (score 1):

No sé dónde oí esto, y es posible que lo haya imaginado.  Pero bien:

*Cuando un ancianito ya se acerca a su hora de morir, se puede hablar de preparar su cama, o prepararle la cama (de muerte).*

*El ancianito mismo podría decir, después de gran estrés, "Prepárame mi cama, ya no aguanto más".*

Podría ser que se relacione con eso.  En la política, si alguien se humilla, va a tener ganas de esconderse en alguna cueva en alguna parte, rendirse, dejar de luchar.

Comment: Regarding my edit, I did not mention the reasoning behind it: [_El punto se escribirá siempre detrás de las comillas_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5349/1674) says RAE.

Comment: @fedorqui - I wonder if it's like the US/UK divide on quotation marks.  US: "It's like this."  UK: 'It's like this'.  (I think.)

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was always the US style, since this is what I see in [se]. I just found [this explanation](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-quotation-marks): _in American English we always put periods and commas inside quotation marks, but in British English periods and commas can go inside or outside_. In Spanish, it is always the way I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Según parece cama era antiguamente sinónimo de ataúd.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!